# Centering a tilted camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, camera

I'm trying to make a tile-based game in Unity, and i want to have a function, that centers the camera on a chosen tile.
The problem is that the camera is tilted (70 degrees), and when i try to change it's transform.position to match the position of the tile, it's not correct.
I've tried some trygonometric functions (sin and such), but it didn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try childing camera to the tile and changing it mannualy if it doesnt work try making a fuction that changes the position and the rotation as you like (ex if x + 1 rotate 55 degrees y ... this is just VERY abstract...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the camera directly, parent it to a `GameObject` that's directly above the tile.  Then when you need to move the camera, just move that `GameObject`.

You will be using the distance between the `camera` and it's parent as an offset so you will not have to do any calculations about where to place the camera.